# How to deal with annotations in kotlin multiplatform data classes?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

Recently I have split my KMP project into fullstack project and a core library (that is mostly consists of common data classes) and found out that I need to use an annotation from JVM library on one of the data classes that is now defined in a common module.

It doesn't seems possible to use an annotation from Java library in Kotlin common code.

What are the possible ways to resolve such issue preferrebly avoiding declaring such data class via `expect` and then repeating its implementation in `actual` platforms but with different annotations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can `expect/actual` the annotation it self.

Say, if you have a JVM annotation like so, `@Entity`

you can have files like `src/commonMain/Entity.kt`

```kotlin
  expect annotation class Entity()
```

and in `src/androidMain/Entity.kt`

```kotlin
  actual typealias Entity = package.to.Entity
```

and in `src/iosMain/Entity.kt`

```kotlin
  actual annotation class Entity()
```

Now you can go ahead use it in your common code

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Movies(
  val title: String,
  val release: Int
)
```

Comment: Okay, but what if I have different annotation signatures on JVM and JS (different libraries.) How can unify the common annotation as `typealias` won't simply do the trick?

Comment: actually, typealias does the trick if you have different targets. But to help you more, I should probably know more. Do you have like two different annotations for jvm and js? o do you have one annotation with different implementations? if it's one annotation with different implementations, then typealias can do the trick there

Comment: Well, I have some polymorphism on my data classes, that requires some annotations to support it in serialization libraries I'll have to use. There are currently Jackson for JVM and Kotlin Serialization on JS. They have different APIs. I am not sure how to deal with Korlin Serialization yet.

Comment: Late reply: Kotlin Serialization works both on JVM and JS. Best bet was to go with it. And good news it is even stable now. running 1.0.1 on production

Comment: is still not clear how to list annotations of given KClass<T> in common code ?